# How to copy current running script to another folder

Tags: ruby, file

I need my script to copy itself to another folder. I was trying to do it with `FileUtils` like this, but I don't know how to refer to the current file instead of`###`.

```
FileUtils.cp('###', 'C:\Users\Public\Documents')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
__FILE__
```

.....................

Comment: The thing is that I make an exe file using ocra. But it still copies the .rbw file.

Comment: Not sure what all those files are. You haven't mentioned anything like that in your question. It is your responsibility.

Comment: I don't blame anybody accept myself. Than can you please tell a solution for this case?